# Split One Google Sheet into Multiple Sheets based on Column Value - Replace Duplicate Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is getting to be above my level of knowledge and I was hoping for assistance. The script below works with some limits. This script checks to see if a region tab exists, if it doesn't, the regional data from the source worksheet is copied to a new tab by the name of that region. Region is column 24 on the source worksheet, the data starts on row 3 and the header is Row 2.

If the region tab already exists I would like for it to be deleted recreated or repopulated with current data instead of being skipped over.

```
function createSheets(){

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const sourceWS = ss.getSheetByName("Forecast (SQL) Validation")

const regions = sourceWS
  .getRange(3,24,sourceWS.getLastRow()-2,1)
  .getValues()
  .map(rng => rng[0])

const uniqueRegion = [ ...new Set(regions) ]

const currentSheetNames = ss.getSheets().map(s => s.getName())

let ws

uniqueRegion.forEach(region => {

  if(!currentSheetNames.includes(region)){

    ws = null
    ws = ss.insertSheet()
    ws.setName(region)
    ws.getRange("A2").setFormula(`=FILTER('Forecast (SQL) Validation'!A3:CR,'Forecast (SQL) Validation'!X3:X="${region}")`)
    sourceWS.getRange("A2:CR2").copyTo(ws.getRange("A1:CR1"))

}//If regions doesn't exist

})//forEach loop through the list of region

} //close createsheets functions
```

Comment: The question needs more focus: 1) Only one "improvement" (question) per post 2) "I would like for it to be deleted recreated or repopulated" --> choose one.

Comment: `recreated or repopulated with current data` That's what's going on with the tabs which don't yet exist, right? So it would be done the same way with tabs that already exist, just that the older ones should be deleted or modified. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Try it this way

```
function createSheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName("Forecast (SQL) Validation");
  const regions = ssh.getRange(3, 24, ssh.getLastRow() - 2, 1).getValues().flat();
  const urA = [...new Set(regions)];
  const shnames = ss.getSheets().map(s => s.getName())
  let ws;
  urA.forEach(region => {
    let idx = shnames.indexOf(region);
    if (~idx) {
      ss.deleteSheet(ss.getSheetByName(shnames(idx)));//if it does exist delete it and create a new one
    }//if it does not exist the just create a new one
    ws = null;
    ws = ss.insertSheet(region);
    ws.getRange("A2").setFormula(`=FILTER('Forecast (SQL) Validation'!A3:CR,'Forecast (SQL) Validation'!X3:X="${region}")`)
    ssh.getRange("A2:CR2").copyTo(ws.getRange("A1:CR1"))
  })
}
```

#### Explanation:

Loop through all tabs, and if the tab already exists, delete it via [deleteSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deletesheetsheet) before creating it again, as you are doing with the non-existent ones..